# Lagrange Multipliers where the Constraint is an Inequality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm currently learning about Lagrange multipliers in my multivariate calculus class and all of the problems we've been studying have had the constraint in the form of an equation $(g(x,y,z) = k)$ - however, I've also sometimes seen that problems involve both an equality constraint and an inequality constraint $(g(x,y,z) ≤ k)$ with the same expression. My intuition is that you can use Lagrange on the boundary (maximizing/minimizing $f(x,y,z)$ with constraint $g(x,y,z) = k$) and use partials for the interior (finding where $f(x,y,z)$ vanishes), but I'm not certain that this is the correct approach. Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a generalisation of the Lagrange Multiplier theorem with regards to constraining inequalities by Karush-Kuhn-Tucker:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions